# R - store distance matrix in Rcpp

Tags: r, matrix, distance, rcpp

I have trouble figuring out how to store a distance matrix in `Rcpp`.

Let us imagine that I want to store the following function in a distance matrix of `n*n` individuals (I don't square the `sum` because I am unsure how to do so in `rcpp`.

```
distxy = function(x,y) sum (x - y)
```

In this example I want to pairwise compare 3 individuals

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   24   24   22   20
[2,]   21   24   30   20
[3,]   44   34   41   13
```

In `R` I would loop the function through a matrix like this

```
mat = matrix(0, nrow(d), nrow(d))

  len = nrow(d)
  mat = matrix(0, len, len)

  for(j in 1:len){
    for(i in 1:len){
      mat[j,i] = distxy( d[j,], d[i,] ) 
    }
  }
```

and get (I can square the results, but this in unimportant here)

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0   -5  -42
[2,]    5    0  -37
[3,]   42   37    0
```

I am having trouble doing the same in `rcpp`

What I achieved so far is

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector FunCpp(NumericMatrix x) {
  int nrow = x.nrow();
  NumericMatrix out(nrow);

  for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < nrow; j++) { 
      out[i,j] = sum( x(i,_) - x(j,_) ) ; 
    }
  }
  return out;
}
```

But the distance matrix is incorrect. Any idea ?

```
d = rbind(c(24, 24, 22, 20), 
      c(21, 24, 30, 20), 
      c(44, 34, 41, 13))
```

Comment: Please do not misuse StackOverflow as a C++ tutoring service.  This is the second question in a short time period which shows _elementary_ errors.  I think you may need to brush up your C++ before embarking on more ambitious Rcpp adventures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of syntax mistakes in your Rcpp code:

- Returning a `NumericVector` instead of a `NumericMatrix`
- Using `operator[]` to index by two dimensions (`out[i,j]`)

Here is a cleaned up version:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

inline double distxy(Rcpp::NumericVector x, Rcpp::NumericVector y) {
    return Rcpp::sum(x - y);
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericMatrix FunCpp(Rcpp::NumericMatrix x) {
    int nrow = x.nrow();
    Rcpp::NumericMatrix out(nrow);

    for (int i = 0; i < nrow; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nrow; j++) { 
            out(j, i) = distxy(x.row(j), x.row(i)); 
        }
    }

    return out;
}
```

---

Testing against your R function,

```
m <- matrix(
    c(24, 24, 22, 20,
      21, 24, 30, 20,
      44, 34, 41, 13),
    nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE
)

all.equal(FunR(m), FunCpp(m))
#[1] TRUE
```

---

As for squaring, you can use `std::pow` inside of `distxy`,

```
return std::pow(Rcpp::sum(x - y), 2);
```

or inside of `FunCpp` in your inner loop:

```
out(j, i) = std::pow(distxy(x.row(j), x.row(i)), 2);
```

---

```
distxy <- function(x,y) sum(x - y) 

FunR <- function(d) {
    len <- nrow(d)
    mat <- matrix(0, len, len)

    for(j in 1:len){
        for(i in 1:len){
            mat[j,i] <- distxy(d[j,], d[i,]) 
        }
    }
    mat
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I really appreciate. I really have trouble with `c++`.